# Any way to read / write a floppy disk in a modern computer?

Tags: floppy

I recently bought a new computer. The motherboard only has SATA connections, no PATA or Floppy.

I also have a (piano-style) keyboard that allows reading and writing of midi files from a 3.5" floppy disk, which would be fun to play around with.

Is anyone aware of a method of reading and writing from a 3.5" floppy disk, preferably from an internal disk drive?

Comment: Microsoft and Apple both support 3.5" floppy disk drives within their current operating systems.  There are both SATA and USB floppy drives on the market.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can purchase USB floppy disk drives from most places.

Since you particularly want this just to communicate with your keyboard, it might be worth checking to see if you can't achieve this over MIDI. There is a binary transfer protocol that operates over MIDI that a lot of Yamaha keyboards that I know of support, yours might too. Check the manual.

Comment: +1 for MIDI. Also, most modern music equipment supports MIDI over USB, but some equipment supports MIDI over older-style [MIDI connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI#Connectors) & cables (5-pin DIN) - You can get [add-ons](http://www.gear4music.com/Recording-and-Computers/Phonic-Midihub-USB-MIDI-Interface/O7J) for PCs that allow you to connect using these older-style connectors if your keyboard has no USB connector.

Comment: Yeah mine's older and it has the 5-pin connectors. I'll accept this answer if no one proposes an internal solution.

Comment: If you want an internal solution to avoid a cable mess: You can get a USB based floppy drive, dismantle it and connect it internally. No external cable hassle. :)       (Or, only completeness sake and not as a practical solution: You can swap to a modern motherboard with an on-board floppy connector. They do exist. Once more: It is not practical unless you remember to check for it during the next upgrade, whenever that is.)

Comment: @Hennes Have you ever seen a how-to or anything on the subject of making an external drive internal?

Comment: No, but the sole external USB floppy I've handled consisted of a standard 3.5 inch drive, some electronics and a case. As long as the drive fits (it should) then it is just either of going the ugly way and leading the wire outside, or changing the plug from normal 4 pins external USB to 4 pins internal USB. The latter assumes you have a free USB header on the motherboard. If you check that before cutting off the plug then you are smarter than I was.